# T-SQL filtering an aggregate column via CTE or subquery with column from view

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case, aggregate, common-table-expression

In SQL Server and am trying to filter results from a calculation where 
`sum(OutShares) > 5`. Can't use aggregate in Where clause, and having will only filter out `symbol > 5`, does not aggregate the aggregate. I believe I need to use a CTE or subquery.

```
select 
    symbol, sum(qty) * cast(Shares as decimal) As OutShares, last_name
from 
    holding h
join 
    security s on h.id = s.id
join 
    account a on h.p = a.p
join 
    manager m on a.aid = m.id
where 
    OutShares > 5.0
group by 
    symbol, last_name;
```

Results:

```
Symbol  OutShares       last_name
---------------------------------
ATI     2.087600649     Jill
ATI     2.546492791     Bernie
ATI     1.13889437      Evie
ATI     1.603800006     Luke
BO      5.00000000      Jack
```

Desired results:

```
Symbol  OutShares       last_name
------------------------------------------------
ATI     7.38            Jill Bernie Evie Luke
BO      5.00            Jack
```

Comment: Desired Results

Comment: sql server version please?

Comment: I noticed that you have each last name listed out in your desired result. It also seems that you have summed up the outshares grouped by Symbol. In your example, nothing is filtered out by the `sum(OutShares) >5`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can use cte below way

```
with cte as
(
select symbol, sum(qty) * cast(Shares as decimal) As OutShares, last_name
from holding h
join security s on h.id=s.id
join account a on h.p = a.p
join manager m on a.aid=m.id
group by symbol, last_name
) select * from cte where OutShares>5
```

But from your desired result it seems to me you need `STRING_AGG()` if it is sql server 2017

```
with cte as
    (
    select symbol, sum(qty) * cast(Shares as decimal) As OutShares, last_name
    from holding h
    join security s on h.id=s.id
    join account a on h.p = a.p
    join manager m on a.aid=m.id
    group by symbol, last_name
    ) select symbol,sum(OutShares),
      STRING_AGG(last_name, ', ') as last_name from cte
      group by symbol
```

below sql server version

```
with cte as
        (
        select symbol, sum(qty) * cast(Shares as decimal) As OutShares, last_name
        from holding h
        join security s on h.id=s.id
        join account a on h.p = a.p
        join manager m on a.aid=m.id
        group by symbol, last_name
        )

select symbol, sum(OutShares),
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + t2.last_name
         from cte t2
         where t1.symbol= t2.symbol
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') name
from cte t1 group by symbol
```

Comment: don't forget the `where outshares>5` part in your second code block :-)

Comment: The results of the last code from Zaynud Abadin Tuhin brings up all OutShares.  Greatly appreciate the help. I am using SQL Server version  2012.   Is there a way to filter OutShares > 5?  Adding a where clause in outer query filters out resulting symbols that have multiple rows.

Comment: Apologies for the latest question...I added  'Having OutShares>5' after 'group by symbol', having accomplished this task.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  select symbol, sum(qty) * cast(Shares as decimal) As OutShares, last_name
  from holding h
  join security s on h.id=s.id
  join account a on h.p = a.p
  join manager m on a.aid=m.id
  group by symbol, last_name
)
SELECT Symbol,
       SUM(OutShares) OutShares,
       STUFF(
              (
                SELECT ' '+ Last_Name
                FROM CTE TT
                WHERE TT.Symbol = T.Symbol
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
       ) last_name
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Symbol;
```