# Filter SQL by Aggregate Not in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, filter, aggregate

Can you filter a SQL table based on an aggregated value, but still show column values that weren't in the aggregate statement?

- My table has only 3 columns: "Composer_Tune", "_Year", and "_Rank".
- I want to use SQL to find which "Composer_Tune" values are repeated in each annual list, as well as which ranks the duplicated items had.
- Since I am grouping by "Composer_Tune" & "Year", I can't list "_Rank" with my current code.
- The image shows the results of my original "find the duplicates" query vs what I want:

[Current vs Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWJBb.png)

- I tried applying the concepts in this [Aggregate Subquery StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089278/t-sql-filtering-an-aggregate-column-via-cte-or-subquery-with-column-from-view) but am still getting "_Rank is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" from this code:

```
  WITH DUPE_DB AS (SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.[NAME] GROUP BY Composer_Tune, _Year HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
  SELECT Composer_Tune, _Year, _Rank    
  FROM DUPE_DB
```

Comment: You could *join* your Dupe_DB with a table that contains Rank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly declare the columns used in the Group By expression in the select columns.
You can use the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) if you are using transact sql for the proper use of Group By.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the aggregated resultset to original unit level table:

```sql
WITH DUPE_DB AS (
    SELECT Composer_Tune, _Year 
    FROM DB.dbo.[NAME] 
    GROUP BY Composer_Tune, _Year 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) 

SELECT n.Composer_Tune, n._Year, n._Rank 
FROM DB.dbo.[NAME] n
INNER JOIN DUPE_DB
  ON n.Compuser_Tune = DUPE_DB.Composer_Tune
  AND n._Year = DUPE_DB._Year
ORDER n.Composer_Tune, n._Year
```